# SSIS package-scoped variable populated from procedure output variable in a loop

Tags: ssis

Have a stored procedure that has an output param.  This procedure is called within a foreach loop.  For some reason, one iteration failed, since I have a task immediately following this task that executes based on a constraint if the return code is > 0.

When this procedure runs successful, the output variable value is 0 and this other task (a sql task to log some info) will never run.

However, it did run for this one iteration and I was able to reset the data being passed in and step into it.  The sql task that follows the stored procedure was hit because of the constraint which looks at the variable mapped to the output param from the procedure call.

What is strange is that I took the exact same parameters and their values and called the procedure directly in SSMS and got an output parameter value = 0, whereas in SSIS, the task executed and got > 0.

This leads me to wonder if the output parameter is not being applied to the variable for some reason in some cases?

Should I manually re-set the value of the variable back to 0, after going down the error path?

[ update ]

Resolved - if a sql task isnt returning the value you think it is, fire up sql profiler and watch that your sending in.  Might just be surprised that your sending in something "slightly" different. :=)

[image]

Comment: What is the expression constraint logic?

Comment: @variable > 0, and evaluation operation is "expression or constraint", so either task failure or that variable is > 0.  AlsoI just now debugged it again, and when I hit a breakpoint on that task, the variable in question was 0, so that would mean the task failed, yet I see no error message in the debug window

Comment: Correction to above comment.  The variable was 0 at the point of that task executing, and > 0 afterwards, so that would be enough to trigger the constraint (in red).  I captured the sql statement via profiler as well and am now comparing it to the statement I issued directly in SSMS.

Comment: Woot!  I just figured it out, thanks to firing up profiler.  One of the values the statement being sent across was indeed different than I was using in SSMS.  Turns out it was a datatype casting issue between numeric and money